# HTML drop down list output paragraph Change

Tags: html

I have a dropdown list on my html code, and theres a paragraph under the dropdown list.

In my dropdown list and a submit button. I can pick different animals- Dog, Cat, Mouse, and Bird. If a person pick Cat, i want the paragraph under the dropdown list to change to "Meow" after the person picks Cat and pressed submit. How can i do this?

Comment: @Jawa just the drop down list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Attach `change` event listener to select to do something when it changes

```js
document.getElementById("select").addEventListener('change', function() {
    if (this.value == "Cat") { 
      document.getElementById("res").innerHTML = "Meow"; 
    } else {
      document.getElementById("res").innerHTML = null; 
    }
});
```

```html
<select id="select">
    <option value="Dog">Dog</option>
    <option value="Cat">Cat</option>
    <option value="Mouse">Mouse</option>
    <option value="Bird">Bird</option>
</select>
<p id="res"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<select id = 'select'>
    <option value = "Dog">Dog</option>
    <option value = "Cat">Cat</option>
    <option value = "Mouse">Mouse</option>
    <option value = "Bird">Bird</option>
</select>
<p id = 'id-name'></p>
```

JavaScript:

```
var value = document.getElementByID('select').value;
if(value = "Cat") {
    document.getElementByID('id-name').innerHTML = "Meow";
}
```

That may work.